# Data not getting added to the xml node? Getting error: output error : invalid character value

Tags: c, libxml2

I am trying to build and xml and trying to add an big chunk of string to an xml node. 
I am getting three errors very regularily(not all three errors everytime). Here are the three errors:

```
output error : string is not in UTF-8
xml escape entities char out of range
output error : invalid character value
```

In the case of first two errors the data gets added to the xml node even when the error gets displayed. But when I get the third error that is `output error : invalid character value` the string data is not getting added to the xml node. Do not know where is it going wrong.

Can someone direct me to solve the above issue? I am using libxml2 library and in C platform

Answer (score 2):

The error `string is not in UTF-8` should be self-explanatory. libxml2 expects all input strings (`xmlChar *`) to be encoded in UTF-8.

The error `xmlEscapeEntities : char out of range` occurs if you add ASCII control chars that are not allowed in XML 1.0 which includes all ASCII characters from 0 to 31 except tab, newline and carriage return (0x09, 0x0A, 0x0D).

The error `invalid character value` can occur for all kinds of characters that are not allowed in XML 1.0. For example, ASCII control chars, Unicode surrogates or other invalid Unicode code points.

So you're adding strings with invalid UTF-8, invalid ASCII control chars, or both. The solution is to sanitize your input first.